# In what medium can I store a 2 component clear coat (unmixed)

Tags: paint, paint-clearcoat, storage

I just bought some 2 component clear coat: [MIPA 2K HS Klarlack CS 85](https://www.mipa-paints.com/fileadmin/product/gb/pi/lm/2K-HS-KlarlackCS85.pdf)

I bought it together with a hardener and some thinner both of which have caps that can be screwed on and off. However, the clear coat itself does not have a cap, it just has a flat surface with a boxcutter symbol (from which I take that I'll have to cut it open and will not be able to seal it again).

Now I won't be using all of my clear coat in one go so I'd like to store it in a container when not in use. The thing is I don't know if the clear coat fluid has any properties that make certain storage mediums a poor choice. So I wanted to run it past some people before cans start exploding or leaking noxious fumes.

My current ideas are:

- An old paint can
- A glass mason jar
- An old cleaned UV curable resin container (black plastic so protects from sunlight)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you keep it covered up when you're not using it and you didn't mix hardener with the clear it will last outa the heat on the shelf for about 3 or 4 years.i got some that 7 years now.